# Number of words with 1 ahead of 2

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Let A = {0, 1, 2, 3, .....9} be a set consisting of different digits. The number of ways in which a nine digit number can be made in which 1 and 2 are present and 1 is always ahead of 2 and repetition of digits is not allowed is $(8!*x)/2$. What is x?

My attempt: Let the one's place of the nine digit number be filled with 2. Then there are 8 ways in which 1 can be kept and the remaining positions can be filled in 8! ways. If the  tenth's place is filled with 2 then there are 7 ways in which 1 can be placed and 8! ways in which the other digits can be arranged.

Proceeding in this way......

```
                 Total no. of ways=(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)*8! = 36*8!.
```

But, this gives an answer for x no were near the original answer of 65. What was wrong in my method?

Comment: Half the time $1$ comes before $2$ and half the time it is comes after, so we don't need to worry much about that part.

Comment: Yes, worry about the combinations aspect, then just divide by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about who is ahead of whom. If we leave out $0$, there are $9!$ numbers. If we leave out any of the other $7$ digits that can be left out, we have $8\cdot 8!$ possibilities, since $0$ cannot be the first digit. The total is $9\cdot 8! +(7)(8)8!$, which is $(65)(8!)$.

In half of these, $1$ is ahead of $2$ and in half of them it is behind $2$.

Comment: Why did you write 9! as 9*8!?

Comment: Oh never mind, I see

Comment: So that I could take out the common factor $8!$ from $9!$ and $(7)(8)(8!)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  How that 8*8! sir? If we leave 0 and any other number from the seven which can be left out there are only 8 numbers left and we have to make a number with 9 digits without repetition. How is it possible?

Comment: We are keeping $0$ and $8$ other digits. The first digit can be anything but $0$, $8$ choices. That leaves $8$ digits that can be arranged in any order, total $8\cdot 8!$. But there are $7$ ways to leave out a digit which is none of $0,1,2$, total $(7)(8\cdot 8!)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : for each $i<j$ let us denote by
$N_{i,j}$ the number of solutions where the $2$ is on the $i$-th
place and the $1$ is in the $j$-th place.

Then $N_{ij}$ is independent of $i,j$, it is always equal to [fill the blank].

Answer (score 0):

$0$ must not be the leading digit, so we split into two cases, depending on whether or not $0$ is one of the digits. For the moment, let's not worry about which order $1$ and $2$ are put in. If $0$ is *not* one of the digits, then each other number in the set is a digit. How many ways are there to arrange these digits? If $0$ *is* a digit, then there are $7$ ways to choose the number in the set that isn't a digit. How many ways are there to arrange the chosen digits, since $0$ can't come first? Thus, how many $9$-digit numbers containing $1$ and $2$ with no repeated digits are there. Observing that $1$ comes ahead of $2$ half the time, then dividing by $2$ will get us the desired number, which will allow us to solve for $x$.